# A private chat room linked to my blog and piqued my curiosity

Tags: discussion, chat

I recently [blogged about Stack Overflow](http://yoursumbuddy.com/my-stack-overflow-habit/). Soon after, I got 20 page views (a noticeable amount for my humble site) from https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/357. I went there and got an "Access Denied" page with a message saying it was a private chat room (I understand these are reserved for moderators). There was a "Request Access" button, so I clicked it. I've had the page up in my browser for 24 hours or so and it says:

"You have requested access to this room; please be patient while the room owners process your request."

I'm happy to be patient. Patience is one of my favorite qualities. However, should it not pay off in this case, is there any way to slake my curiosity about what went down in that room?

Comment: @iStimple Nope, our secret hiding place is on chat.SE, not chat.meta.SE, and it's room 4. :-P

Comment: The employees were talking about you, uh oh. Beware unicorn ninjas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We use several chat.meta.stackexchange rooms internally for company chat, your blog post was linked to in one of them and it was apparently a popular message if it showed up on your referral log :) I can't quite show proof since there's lots of other unrelated messages in the room, but people were impressed (specially with your 780 consecutive visits).

Comment: Thanks for the info. Nice to hear!